# Is it allowed to bring sex toys on a flight to Singapore?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, legal, singapore, singapore-airlines, sex

I'll be taking a flight from Tokyo to Singapore. If I take a "pocket pussy" (artificial vagina) as carry on, will it be confiscated? Also will it be removed from my bag? I'm traveling with my family and don't want any embarrassment.

Comment: Bringing it as a carry-on may give the impression that you need access to it while on the plane, which the airline may frown upon.

Answer (score 14):

As already noted, airport security in Tokyo won't care.  Your problem is going to be **the laws in Singapore**, specifically the [Singapore Penal Code, article 292](http://statutes.agc.gov.sg/aol/search/display/view.w3p;ident=2c9207ab-e814-4e97-8e23-41bbd483042b;page=0;query=DocId%3A%22025e7646-947b-462c-b557-60aa55dc7b42%22%20Status%3Ainforce%20Depth%3A0;rec=0):

> Sale of obscene books, etc.
>
> 292.—(1)  Whoever —
>
> (a) [...] has in his possession any obscene book, pamphlet, paper, drawing, painting, representation or figure, or **any
>   other obscene object whatsoever**;
>
> (b) **imports**, exports, transmits by electronic means or conveys any obscene object for any of the purposes aforesaid, [...]
>
> shall be punished with imprisonment for a term which may extend to 3
>   months, or with fine, or with both.

So the rub (so to speak) is, what's "obscene"?  Singapore traditionally took a pretty dim view of sex toys, but they've opened up a bit and there are actually multiple sex toy shops in the city now.  The red line appears to be realism: lurid pink and purple tentacles are OK, realistic penises not so much.

My best guess is that your artificial vagina is *likely* OK, but I'm not sure I would like to have this debate with an eagle-eyed Customs officer.  That said, Customs concentrates on cigarettes, drugs and alcohol, roughly in that order: unless you raise suspicions of smuggling one of these three, it's unlikely your bags will even be opened.

Comment: You haven't addressed the embarrassment angle, which is the only reason for concern mentioned in the question.

Comment: @phoog Being handcuffed and escorted away by cops to a Singaporean jail sounds pretty embarrassing to me...

Comment: That is certainly true.  What I meant was that it is possible to be embarassed in Tokyo even though the airport security forces might permit the item in question to be carried onto the plane.

Answer (score 7):

You have two issues: what will security in Tokyo do, and what will customs in Singapore do?

Security doesn't care what your stuff is for, or where you are going, they just care if it looks like something that might be dangerous, or is on top of something that might be dangerous. Having anything embarrassing in carry on is risky. They will root through your bag in front of everyone,  open things and look inside them, etc. You can try to reduce this by being super careful about everything else in your bag - no liquids or gels, nothing knife-like, etc - but you can't be sure. To be sure, put the item in checked luggage or don't bring it.

Your title asks if you can bring the item to Singapore and you've tagged it customs-and-immigration. If you are selected for extra scrutiny by customs, generally you are by yourself when they search the bags. If they confiscate it, your family will probably not see what happens. A traveler I know tells me there are large signs as you enter Singapore reminding you what you can't bring and they are very specific - no guns, no piranha fish - so if sex toys are not allowed you will probably see a sign saying so. No sign, no worries.

Comment: If he would see a sign on the airport saying he can't bring them, it would already be too late. Aren't there any online documents about these rules?

Comment: I didn't find anything online. But in all the airports where I have seen such signs, they are above amnesty boxes where you can get rid of things you aren't allowed to bring in. So it's not too late.

Comment: @KateGregory unless the point is to avoid embarrassment in front of the family.

Comment: I already addressed that - you generally go through secondary alone.

Comment: @KateGregory are the amnesty boxes in secondary?

Comment: @phoog One would presume not... otherwise a traveler could decide to *only* throw out their illegal things *if* they were selected for extra screening.

Comment: @immibis I agree. That was more of a rhetorical question.

Answer (score 4):

Even if your bag contains no prohibited items, there is a chance that the security agent will *suspect* the presence of a prohibited item and search your bag. In addition, there is a chance that someone will see an image of any embarrassing item on the x-ray scanner screen.

Therefore, it is possible to answer this question without knowing whether any given embarrassing item is allowed: the only certain way to avoid embarrassment is to leave the embarrassing item behind.

Comment: The question referenced a specific type of sex toy, but an earlier edit to the title made the title more general while retaining the question's level of specificity. This is probably answerable for the OP's specific item, right?

Comment: @davidvc sure, but why give a specific answer when a general answer suffices?