# Can I have a sex toy in checked-in luggage traveling to Singapore?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, regulations, singapore, sex

I will be moving to Singapore and since the country has very strict rules I wonder if it is possible to take one sex toy with me in checked-in luggage?

I want to respect all local rules and avoid any issues (it is a pink vibrator - not very realistic design packed in its original metal case). I can not find any official information regarding this online. If any of you knows about any official website where I can read more I will be thankful. Singaporean Airlines don't provide any information.

Comment: Do remove battery!!

Comment: Thank you all, that I was thinking about, of course not cabin luggage. Yes and no batteries. But anyway, I wanted to know if I am not breaking any rule with it. It does not have a realistic shape.. 
Thank you @pnuts I read the UPA ch.338 but they don't mention anything about that.. It is difficult to follow the rules if the rules are not clear. I have to find some official information talking about exactly those things. I am sure there is lot of people who would like to know this.

Comment: As long as you follow pnuts link, ch338 does seem to include objects under their term 'publications' so that document is quite straightforward then.

Comment: Related - but not quite the same - http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/73303/is-it-allowed-to-bring-sex-toys-on-a-flight-to-singapore?rq=1

Comment: You two have a good point here. You could either get a mod to dupe-close and refund or leave open and re-answer here, since while the answer is the same, the questions are different (and also the item in question, but that's a different discussion...). @AleksG

Answer (score 6):

**Yes**,  that will be fine.  You can even buy pink vibrators in Singapore itself these days:

http://www.lilyhush.com/fun-factory-stronic-eins-thrusting-vibrator-pink/